# how to read and write (update) the same file using spark (scala)

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I want to update a CSV file depending on some condition, for that I read the file, made all the needed update, however when I tried to write it I'm getting a `FileNotFoundException`.

I think that it is due to the writing process, because when I access the path (where the input/output file were located) I find it empty.

Is there a better way to update a file? And if not, how can I resolve the `FileNotFoundException` error?

Comment: Write to another path, delete the old one and rename/move the new one?

Comment: checkpointing is a better idea as said by Raphael. Please check my answer as well which works in my project. If you like them remove the -ve vote because it is not a wrong answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can do it either by writing a temporary table/csv or using `checkpointing` :

This works :

```
sparkSession.sparkContext.setCheckpointDir("tmp")

ss.read.csv("test.csv") // read existing csv
  .withColumn("test",lit(1)) // modify
  .checkpoint(eager = true) // checkpoint, write to disk
  .write.mode("overwrite") 
  .csv("test.csv") // write to same location
```

Comment: This will work as well as the way described below - write to new file, delete, rename.  That is the way I have coded in my project. My answer is not wrong.